# The declaration `using namespace C;` is essential to prove the results shown in the Example in [namespace.udir]/3

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

As far as I know, the declaration `using namespace C;` below in namespace `D` is **essential** for the compiler to complain about the ambiguity between the *qualified-id*s `B::C::i` and `A::i` in the code below, which is an example in the C++ Standard in [[namespace.udir]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udir#3):

```
namespace A {
  int i;
  namespace B {
    namespace C {
      int i;
    }
    using namespace A::B::C;
    void f1() {
      i = 5;        // OK, C​::​i visible in B and hides A​::​i
    }
  }
  namespace D {
    using namespace B;
    //using namespace C;
    void f2() {
      i = 5;        // ambiguous, B​::​C​::​i or A​::​i?
    }
  }
  void f3() {
    i = 5;          // uses A​::​i
  }
}
void f4() {
  i = 5;            // ill-formed; neither i is visible
}
```

Surprisingly, all three compilers VS2017, GCC and [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac78336a219424e8) show the same error message when the declaration `using namespace C;` is commented out of the code. What am I missing?

> ```
> main.cpp:17:13: error: reference to 'i' is ambiguous
>        i = 5;      // ambiguous, B::C::i or A::i?
> ```

Comment: `using namespace A::B::C;` seems to be sufficient to introduce the ambiguity into the `B` namespace, from `D`'s point of view, when it uses `B`, so also using `C` seems to be unnecessary, indeed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ambiguity is on account of the earlier using directives:

```
namespace B {
// ...
  using namespace A::B::C;
// ...
}
namespace D {
  using namespace B;
```

Since using directives are transitive for unqualified lookup ([[namespace.udir]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udir#4)).